# Swift application not launching on Mavericks

Tags: cocoa, swift, osx-mavericks

Our swift application not launching on mavericks - app icon appears in dock, but no window is visible. No crash happening, and seems like applicationDidFinishLaunching not being called. NSApplication's delegate is connected to AppDelegate in storyboard.

It's easy to repeat that issue, because it doesn't work even with newly created application:

1. Create fresh swift application in Xcode 6.2
2. Change deployment target to 10.9
3. Archive and open app in 10.9 - window is not appearing.

Comment: Actually, it's even more strange - seems like it doesn't launch even if I compile fresh app created on Objective-C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your project is using storyboards. Mac storyboards were introduced in OS X 10.10. Storyboards are not supported in 10.9. Use xib files if you want to support 10.9.